# Securing already connected java sockets with SSL?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have already connected sockets on server and client side and I want to know if it is possible to secure this connection with ssl in java somehow with SSLContext?

I know that client side sockets can be secured like this(with SSL). But i am not sure about connected sockets on server side?

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible on the server side. The [SSLSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class has a [createSocket()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket(java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean)) method just for this purpose. Once you return from the [ServerSocket.accept()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method you have a normal `Socket` that you can layer an `SSLSocket` on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So SSLSocket encapsulates Socket, right? Is it possible to use underlying socket object to send data prior to handshaking. I need that to implement STARTTLS acknowledge message.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the underlying socket to do anything you normally can do with a plain vanilla socket (except of course you cannot shutdown either side or close it), and then "upgrade" it to an SSL socket.